# APNS certificate not shown when generating provisioning profile

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am new in iOS development.
I have created app, then i want to add APNS service, too, so I have generated a new app id which include Notification Service then I have create APNS development and distribution certificate but when I going to generate provision profile using this new app id in add certificate section it will show me only previous development certificates.NOT APNS development certificate so my Question is:

1. Is APNS certificate is necessary to Add in provision profile of new app id
2. If it is necessary then why it not show in certificate section or i am do something wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No APNS certificates are not included in provisioning profiles.

They are used by Apple to ensure that only your server can send Push Notifications to your application.

Although a bit old, but basic concepts are still the same. [Push Notification Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion
but i don't get token id while running the app. It displays following error msg
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application"

Comment: Have you re-generated provisioning profile(with Usual Developer Certificates) and installed it on your mac? 
It looks like the provision that is being used for signing your app does not have correct entitlements. Also make sure your AppId/BundleId is the same.

Comment: same issue for me . Getting Error code 1001 for me.